# Trying to use the Pillow library to create a gif‏

Tags: python, list, gif, python-imaging-library

~This is a university assignment I'm working on. The goal is to create a gif using the Pillow library.

I have approximately 720 images all using the format "a ###.jpg", where # is a number (ie. "a 001.jpg").

With these images, I'm attempting to create a gif by progressively resizing an image (a 001.jpg) 10 times and than use a recursive function that should change to the next image (a 002.jpg) and resize that 10 times, etc...; until it reaches "a 721.jpg", where it should stop.

I'm not familiar with the Pillow library in python, so I'm kind of at a wall right now.
I'm also sure there are plenty of errors or inefficiency in this code.

This will run; however, it will not go on to the next image. I've tried a few things to manipulate the string "a 001.jpg".
Can anyone tell me where the problem is?

```
from PIL import Image

s = ("a 001.jpg")
im = Image.open(s)
def main(im):
    try:
        x = 920
        y = 80
        for a in range(0,10):
            x += 100
            y += 100
            box = (x,y)
            im = im.resize(box)
            im.show()
        s = list(s)
        if s[4] < 9:
            s[4] = int(s[4]) + 1
        elif s[4] == 9:
            s[4] = 0
            s[3] = int(s[3]) + 1
        elif s[3] < 9:
            s[3] = int(s[3]) + 1
        elif s[3] == 9:
            s[3] = 0
            s[2] = int(s[2]) + 1
        elif s[2] < 9:
            s[2] = int(s[2]) + 1
        elif s[2] == 9:
            s[2] = 0
        s = ''.join(s)
        im = Image.open(s)
        return main(im)
    except:
        return -1
main(im)
```

Comment: you are comparing strings to ints and only comparing and updating a single character at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is the problem:

```
s = list(s)
```

You may think that `s` is global variable, but for python `s` is local variable, due to assignment. To make `s` global do:

```
def main(im):
    global s
    ...
```

Also you are catching all exceptions, so probably you are not getting any errors. If you really insist on the catching just do the following for now:

```
except Exception as inst:
    raise(inst)
```

This should tell what is happening.

Comment: I completely missed that, thank you.  
Now the problem is still within the lists.  
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()  -  I probably have to convert the str into an int to compare though